# ios: when will the main view of uiviewcontroller be dealloced?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, exc-bad-access

We konw the UIViewController class maintains its main view instance(self.view). I have a tableview(a subview of self.view) with a gesture recognizer. The target of this gesture recognizer is the viewcontroller. But I found a bad access in the crash log(it does not appear on my own device).

```
CrashDoctor Diagnosis: Possible zombie in call: -[MTConversationViewController tableViewDidBeingTouched:UITapGestureRecognizer (instance)]
```

I guess when the viewcontroller is dealloced, the view is not dealloced yet, and its subviews. The viewcontroller becomes a zombie in target method. Is is right? Should we set all of subviews to nil in the dealloc method to avoid bad access in the delegate/target methods?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

@Zhang Jiuzhou,

I think in ARC the self.view is weak property in every viewController subclass we create. So whenever the viewController instance is set to nil. It deallocs all the weak properties it holds. So no need to worry about the view when using ARC for defalut self.view .

I case for custom views We need to remove them using [view removeFromSuperView]; to properly remove them from view hierarchy. And then set viewController instance to nil.

I hope It will help you.

Comment: But how to explain this crash? The viewcontroller is dealloced, but the view can receive touch and call target method. It crashed because the view controller dealloced and became zonbie.

Answer (score 0):

Your gesture recognizer is possibly sending a callback to your controller after your controller has been deallocated. Just make sure you remove the gesture recognizer from the view you attached it to before you deallocate your controller.

For example if you set up your gesture recognizer like so:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    _gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action@selector(gestureHandler:)];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:_gesture];
}
```

Then remove the gesture recognizer in your ViewController's dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [view removeGestureRecognizer:_gesture];
    [_gesture release];
    [view release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```